# How do I compare the single threaded computational power of 2 ARM processors

Tags: arm, cpu, performance

I'm trying to compare ARM processors, namely the A9 and the A53, but I haven't found anything I'd consider reliable .

For instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARM_processors) suggests that the A9 and A53 have a DMIPS/MHz of 2.5 and 2.24 respectively. To me, this suggests that at equal clock frequencies, I could expect the A53 to be marginally slower in a single threaded application. Is this a reasonable first order approximation? How does the 32bit vs 64 bit architecture play into this?

It should be noted that I'm not particularly interested in performance/watt

In contrast to this, [this link](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/the-top-5-things-to-know-about-cortex-a53#:%7E:text=Higher%20performance%20than%20Cortex%2DA9,enables%2015%25%20higher%20frequency%20operation.) suggests that the A53 offers about 20% higher "instruction throughput"

Comment: It depends on the workload..What increases the IPC for modern processors is *parallelism*. Of course instructions can only paralleled if your code has sufficient independent instructions of the right kind (for which there are available execution units in the processor)

Comment: If you need to do lots of operations on data larger than 32 bits, then use a 64-bit processor.  Loading, storing, and operating on 64-bit values using a 32-bit processor is going to be several times slower compared to a 64-bit processor that can often load, compute, or store them in 1 clock cycle.  Common examples would be if you are attaching more than 4GB of RAM, you may have 64-bit pointers.  If you need to use double precision floating point, those are 64 bits.  Multiplying or adding 64-bit numbers, etc.

Comment: DMIPs are almost useless, they don't consider the cache size and efficiency. A more useful benchmark is HINT, it produces a two dimensional output, where the X-axis is a measure of the computational size. You can see the curve change as the code/data runs out of L1 cache, then needs L2 cache, then main memory. You can pick the size value that corresponds to your application. I don't know if there are published results for these processors, you may need to run your own tests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_INTegration